# Can Top Level Domain consists of three parts?

Tags: dns, domain, domain-name, subdomain, tld

Top Level Domains (TLDs) can be general TLDs (.com, .net, etc.) or country-code TLDs like .co.uk, .gov.us, etc.

Question: Can a top level domain consists of three parts? I have a list of domain names that is assumed to be naked (no sub-domains) but I find this domain:

```
al.sp.gov.br
```

Either it is a mistake in the list and the `al` is a sub-domains.

Or, there exist three parts TLDs so that al is a naked domain and `sp.gov.br` is a TLD.

Expert help is needed plz. Can you clarify to me if `.sp.gov.br` is a TLD?

Comment: `.co.uk` is by definition not a TLD.

Comment: I see. But the most important thing is .ac.uk is reserved so I can consider it a TLD. i.e. whatever comes before .ac.uk is the naked domain that the domain owner registered. In my question I am unable to figure out whether sp.gov.br is reserved (like a TLD) or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: Your question isn't about domain levels, it's about the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/).

---

The "levels" are separated by a dot, so they cannot have dots by themselves. So your example domain name `al.sp.gov.br` has four levels:

```
.         (the DNS root)
 └─br       (top-level domain)
    └─gov     (second-level domain)
       └─sp     (third-level domain)
          └─al    (fourth-level domain)
```

*(It is not impossible to have dots in a label, but you will hopefully never see it in practice.)*

---

But "naked domain" is not the same thing as "top-level domain". Most people use the term 'naked domain' to refer to what [RFC 8499](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8499) calls a "zone apex", which is the point where a given (sub-)domain has been delegated to another server. This can occur **at any level.** At this point, you will always find a SOA record, which is why people say "you cannot use CNAME on a naked domain" – it's not because of its level, but because it's the root of a zone and already has a SOA record.

In this sense, most TLDs are "naked domains" and *most* second-level domains are "naked domains", but third-level domains can just as well be "naked domains". So looking at your example again,

- `.` (root) obviously starts a new zone and has a SOA record. It has NS records for 'br'.
- `br` (the TLD) also starts a new zone and has a SOA record. It has NS records for 'gov.br' (although hosted on the same server).
- `gov.br` also has a SOA record, so it also starts a new zone.
- `sp.gov.br` also has a SOA record...
- `al.sp.gov.br` has a SOA record too.

So all of them count as "naked domains" in the usual meaning of that term.

---

Finally, "reserved (like a TLD)" is not the same thing as "naked domain". The former is a matter of policy, while the latter is a technical thing.

It sounds like what you're looking for is called **a "public suffix"** (a domain whose subdomains can be registered by third parties). This, too, can happen at any level and is not something you'll know by just looking at DNS.

Most software which needs to distinguish such "public" domains from "regular" domains uses the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/) maintained by Mozilla. This list indeed includes `sp.gov.br` as a public suffix, meaning that its immediate subdomains (like al.sp.gov.br) are likely to be registered and owned.

The Public Suffix List is available in text form but can be used through a C library called *libpsl*, Python module *publicsufficlist*, and so on.

Comment: Exactly, what I look for is the public-suffix. Thanks.